# Random generation trouble, or script trouble?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flex4

In ideal it must give me 5 black squares on random positions on checker field. But in fact it giving me less up to none black squares.

I really stuck into this because i literally can't find answer.

PS here is compiled app.
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/9288177/CSE/images/Conquester.swf

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" minWidth="800" minHeight="600" creationComplete="main()">
    <s:layout>
        <s:BasicLayout/>
    </s:layout>
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import flash.display.Shape;
            import flash.display.Sprite;

            import mx.core.UIComponent;

            import spark.core.SpriteVisualElement;
            private var rectangle:Sprite = new Sprite();
            private var insterter:UIComponent = new UIComponent();
            private var theme:SpriteVisualElement = new SpriteVisualElement();
            private var yH:int;
            private var xH:int;
            private var grid:Array = new Array();
            const WIDTH:int = 20;
            const HEIGHT:int = 20;
            private function main():void
            {
                var uic:UIComponent = new UIComponent();
                uic.width = uic.height = 50;
                uic.graphics.lineStyle(1,0x888888);
                //uic.graphics.
                //uic.graphics.drawRect(0,0,50,50);
                canvas.rawChildren.addChild(uic);

                const boxW:int = 20;
                const boxH:int = 20;
                const planetnumber:int = 5;


                for(yH = 0; yH < HEIGHT; yH++) {
                    var row:Array = new Array();
                    for (xH = 0; xH < WIDTH; xH++) {

                        uic.graphics.drawRect(boxW*yH,boxH*xH,boxW,boxH);
                        row.push(0);
                    }
                    grid.push(row);
                }
                var currentplanet:int = 0;
                var rw:int;
                var clmn:int;
                var counter:int = 0;
                while (currentplanet < planetnumber)
                {
                    clmn= (Math.random() * (WIDTH-5)) + 5;
                     rw = (Math.random() * (HEIGHT-5)) + 5;
                    if (fieldcheck(rw, clmn) == true)
                    {
                        grid[rw][clmn] = 1;
                        uic.graphics.beginFill(0x000000, 1);
                        uic.graphics.drawRect(boxW*clmn,boxH*rw,boxW,boxH);
                        uic.graphics.endFill();
                        currentplanet++;
                        if (counter == 4)
                        {
                            c4.text=clmn.toString();
                            r4.text=rw.toString();
                        }
                        if (counter == 3)
                        {
                            c3.text=clmn.toString();
                            r3.text=rw.toString();
                            counter++;
                        }
                        if (counter == 2)
                        {
                            c2.text=clmn.toString();
                            r2.text=rw.toString();
                            counter++;
                        }
                        if (counter == 1)
                        {
                            c1.text=clmn.toString();
                            r1.text=rw.toString();
                            counter++;
                        }
                        if (counter == 0)
                        {
                            c0.text=clmn.toString();
                            r0.text=rw.toString();
                            counter++;
                        }




                    }


                }

            }
            private function fieldcheck(iRow:int, iColumn:int):Boolean
            {
                if (grid[iRow][iColumn]==0)
                {
                    if ((iRow > 0)&&(iRow < HEIGHT))
                    {
                        if ((iColumn > 0) && (iColumn < WIDTH))
                            {
                                if ((grid[iRow-1][iColumn-1]==0)&&(grid[iRow][iColumn-1]==0)&&(grid[iRow+1][iColumn-1]==0)&&(grid[iRow-1][iColumn]==0)&&(grid[iRow+1][iColumn]==0)&&(grid[iRow-1][iColumn+1]==0)&&(grid[iRow][iColumn+1]==0)&&(grid[iRow+1][iColumn+1]==0))
                                    {
                                        return true;
                                    }
                            }
                    }
                }
            return false;
            }

            //var rnd:int = (Math.random()* 41) + 10;
            /*if (rnd >= 48) {
            uic.graphics.beginFill(0x000000, 1);
            uic.graphics.drawRect(boxW*y,boxH*x,boxW,boxH);
            uic.graphics.endFill();                         
            }
            else
            {
            uic.graphics.drawRect(boxW*y,boxH*x,boxW,boxH);
            }*/
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
    <mx:Canvas id="canvas" x="34" y="10" width="90%" height="90%" textAlign="center">
    </mx:Canvas>
    <s:Label id="r1" x="34" y="565" width="84" height="11" text="Label"/>
    <s:Label id="r2" x="34" y="575" width="84" height="11" text="Label"/>
    <s:Label id="c2" x="126" y="575" width="77" height="11" text="Label"/>
    <s:Label id="c1" x="126" y="565" width="77" height="11" text="Label"/>
    <s:Label id="r3" x="34" y="585" width="84" height="11" text="Label"/>
    <s:Label id="c3" x="126" y="585" width="77" height="11" text="Label"/>
    <s:Label id="r4" x="215" y="555" width="84" height="11" text="Label"/>
    <s:Label id="c4" x="307" y="555" width="77" height="11" text="Label"/>
    <s:Label id="r0" x="34" y="555" width="84" height="11" text="Label"/>
    <s:Label id="c0" x="126" y="555" width="77" height="11" text="Label"/>
</s:Application>
```

Comment: (almost) works for me on Firefox 3.6 (i) Do you check that you squares do not fall onto the same place? (ii) do you check for off-by-one error so that your squares do not fall outside of the field?

Comment: i checking that - look if "(grid[iRow][iColumn]==0)" and yes i'm checking that they not going outside the field otherwise it will not ascend further because currentplanet++; is inside if-check so function just stuck in repeat until it will get number which lies inside of field (in theory)

Comment: well i already fixed it. Asked myself - answered almost myself.

       private function fieldcheck(iRow:int, iColumn:int):Boolean {
        var xPos:Array = [-1,0,1,-1,1,-1,0,1];
        var yPos:Array = [-1,-1,-1,0,0,1,1,1];
        var tmpX:int;
        var tmpY:int;
        
        for ( var i:int = 0; i < 8; i++)
        {
         tmpX = iRow + xPos[i];
         tmpY = iColumn + yPos[i];
         if ( tmpX < 0 || tmpX >= WIDTH ||
          tmpY < 0 || tmpY >= HEIGHT )
          continue;
         if ( grid[tmpX][tmpY] != 0 )
          return false;
        }
        return true
       }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your little app lies in the fieldcheck function. The problem you are having is, as The_asMan says, an error occurring in the check that it is running. The problem is that while you are doing some bounds checking:

```
if ((iRow > 0)&&(iRow < HEIGHT))
if ((iColumn > 0) && (iColumn < WIDTH))
```

This doesn't cover when you are doing some operations on the iRow and iColumn values to see if neighboring squares have items in them. I changed the fieldcheck operation to the following and it seems to do the trick:

```
private function fieldcheck(iRow:int, iColumn:int):Boolean
{
    // I used looping here as it made the range checks simpler, plus you can
    // extend the range of a boxes space out pretty easily by changing the
    // - 1 and + 1 to a different number
    for(var r:int = iRow - 1; r == iRow + 1; r++) {
        if(r >= 0 && r < HEIGHT) {
            for(var c:int = iColumn - 1; c == iColumn + 1; c++) {
                if(c >= 0 && c < WIDTH) {
                    if(grid[r][c]==1) {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Additionally, consider changing the following lines from:

```
clmn= (Math.random() * (WIDTH-5)) + 5;
rw = (Math.random() * (HEIGHT-5)) + 5;
```

To :

```
clmn= (Math.random() * (WIDTH-5)) + 4;
rw = (Math.random() * (HEIGHT-5)) + 4;
```

This should give you better results with the numbers as the arrays are 0-indexed and the numbers you were generating went from 5-20 instead of 4-19. (I'm assuming that the buffer spots of 0-3 are intentional).

Comment: Your first if statement is redundant if(grid[iRow][iColumn]==0) since you are testing that location with your loops.

Comment: Whoopsie, good point. I merged 2 different thoughts and missed that. Thanks. :)

Comment: I +1 this cause this guy will probably not give you a green checky

Answer (score 0):

This isn't an answer but a comment that is to big to post as a comment.
It was working fine and I saw 5 black squares after a few refreshes I got the following error code.
When this code popped up I got no squares.

```
TypeError: Error #1010: A term is undefined and has no properties.
    at Conquester/fieldcheck()[C:\Users\Smoke_Fumus\Adobe Flash Builder 4.5\Conquester\src\Conquester.mxml:109]
    at Conquester/main()[C:\Users\Smoke_Fumus\Adobe Flash Builder 4.5\Conquester\src\Conquester.mxml:55]
    at Conquester/___Conquester_Application1_creationComplete()[C:\Users\Smoke_Fumus\Adobe Flash Builder 4.5\Conquester\src\Conquester.mxml:4]
    at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEventFunction()
    at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent()
    at mx.core::UIComponent/dispatchEvent()[E:\dev\4.5.1\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\core\UIComponent.as:13128]
    at mx.core::UIComponent/set initialized()[E:\dev\4.5.1\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\core\UIComponent.as:1818]
    at mx.managers::LayoutManager/doPhasedInstantiation()[E:\dev\4.5.1\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\managers\LayoutManager.as:842]
    at mx.managers::LayoutManager/doPhasedInstantiationCallback()[E:\dev\4.5.1\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\managers\LayoutManager.as:1180]
```

Comment: After looking at the crazy if statement you have you are testing for an out of bounds element on the array when you do iRow+1 of iColumn+1